# How to set dataTable value in pojo using setPropertyActionListener?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2

I am working on JSF and Hibernate integration, where i have a dataTable , which contains records from multiple table records.

I just want,  When i click a row the row values should be assigned to respective pojo class .
I identified that we can do it using `setPropertyActionListener`

I  have the following  methods.

- `HQL Query='select a from Personal as a`

  ```
  <p:dataTable var="leavereq" value="#{leaverequest.requestlist}" >
      <p:column headerText="Name" >  
              <h:outputText value="#{leavereq.ename}" />  
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="Action">  
             <p:commandButton id="selectButton" >  
                      <f:setPropertyActionListener  value="#{leavereq}"  target="#{leaverequest.lrb}"  />  
              </p:commandButton>      
      </p:column>
  ```

**Target class:** Personal lrb;

*This is working fine...!!*

- `HQL Query='select a.name,b.eid from Personal as a,Official as b';`

  ```
  <p:dataTable var="leavereq" value="#{leaverequest.requestlist}" >
      <p:column headerText="Name" >  
              <h:outputText value="#{leavereq.ename}" />  
      </p:column>
                  <p:column headerText="Id" >  
              <h:outputText value="#{leavereq.eid}" />  
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="Action">  
              <p:commandButton id="selectButton" >  
                      <f:setPropertyActionListener  value="#{leavereq}"  target="#{leaverequest.lrb}"  />  
              </p:commandButton>      
      </p:column>
  ```

Here the value will be depend on two tables

**Target classes:**
Personal lrb;Official official;

*This is not working !!*

How cal i set the values in two pojo classes using `setPropertyActionListener` ?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem nesting another `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` inside `<p:commandButton>`?

Comment: @Mr.J4mes,,Yes that's fine ..i just asked how to set the dataTable values into pojo classes.